Neo4j 3.5.1 cronjob for taking the backup
I am running Neo4j 3.5.1 using the Helm chart with a cluster of 3 nodes. I am trying to set up periodic backups on Kubernetes using a cron job.
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backupdir-neo4j
  labels:
    app: neo4j-backup
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: neo4j-backup
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: backupdir-neo4j
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: backupdir-neo4j
          containers:
            - name: neo4j-backup
              image: neo4j:3.5.1-enterprise
              env:
                - name: NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT
                  value: "yes"
              volumeMounts:
              - name: backupdir-neo4j
                mountPath: /tmp
              command: ["bin/neo4j-admin",  "backup", "--backup-dir", "/tmp", "--name", "backup", "--from", "neo-helm-neo4j-core-2.neo-helm-neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local:6362"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure

I have set up the cron job to run a backup every 5 minutes. However, I am encountering the following error:
kubectl logs neo4j-backup-28759370-s8xwd
2024-09-05 18:50:27.408+0000 INFO [o.n.b.i.BackupOutputMonitor] Start receiving store files
command failed: Failed to run a backup using the available strategies.

